# Python: Loading all web content in selenium

Tags: python, selenium-webdriver, beautifulsoup

I am trying to retrieve all reviewers comments for a particular app (https://play.google.com/store/apps/details?id=com.getsomeheadspace.android&hl=en&showAllReviews=true) using selenium and beautifulsoup. I load the link by using following code:

```
driver = webdriver.Chrome(path)
driver.get('https://play.google.com/store/apps/details?id=com.tudasoft.android.BeMakeup&hl=en&showAllReviews=true')
```

The above command does not load all reviewers comments. I mean it only loads the first 39 comments and does not load remaining comments. Is there any way to load all comments in single go?

Comment: How about adding some scrolling?

Answer (score 1):

You can use infinite loop and load the page until the `Show More` element is found because of lazy loading.To slowdown the loop I have used `time.sleep(1)`. It gives 200 reviews on that page.If you want to get more then you need to click on `Show More` again.

However some the review format is not supporting hence try..except block.Hope this will helps.

```
from selenium import webdriver
from selenium.webdriver.support.ui import WebDriverWait
from selenium.webdriver.support import expected_conditions as EC
from selenium.webdriver.common.by import By

driver = webdriver.Chrome()
driver.get('https://play.google.com/store/apps/details?id=com.tudasoft.android.BeMakeup&hl=en&showAllReviews=true')

while True:
  driver.execute_script("window.scrollTo(0,document.body.scrollHeight)")
  time.sleep(1)
  elements=WebDriverWait(driver, 10).until(EC.visibility_of_all_elements_located((By.CSS_SELECTOR, 'div.UD7Dzf')))
  if len(driver.find_elements_by_xpath("//span[text()='Show More']"))>0:
      break;

print(len(elements))
allreview=[]
try:
   for review in elements:
       allreview.append(review.text)
except:
    allreview.append("format incorrect")

print(allreview)
```

Answer (score 0):

Looks like you have to scroll down to get all the information on the page.

try this:

`driver.execute_script("window.scrollTo(0,document.body.scrollHeight)")`

You may have to do that a couple of times to load all the data